# Why is my method not returning anything?

Tags: java, algorithm

Why is my method not returning anything?

```
class Test{
    static int count = 0;


    public static void main(String args[]){

    String s = "------+    # ----+------";
        countDoors(s);

    }

    public static int countDoors(String s){
        char sigN= '+';


        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)

            if(s.charAt(i)==sigN)
                count++;


        return count;

    }


}
```

I'm sure kinda a noobish question, but I really wanna understand why it isn't working

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: It ***is*** returning something, you're just not printing the result or doing anything with it.

Comment: where are you calling the function ?

Comment: the code is fine..you just need to use System.out.println() to print the output.

Comment: please add system.out and surely it will print your count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In main() method, you call `countDoors(s);`, it returns `count` value, but you do nothing with it.

If you want to just print this value to console, then change `countDoors(s);` to `System.out.println(countDoors(s));`

If you want to save the result of calling `countDoors(s)` to the variable to make a use of it later, there is an example how you can achieve it:

```
int savedValue = countDoors(s);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was under the impression that when you return something it would print it. Lol thanks bro!

Comment: @Ooguro Glad that I could help you :-)